# How to write query with CASE WHEN in birt?

Tags: java, sql, birt

I have this :

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN `ville_population_2012` < 500 THEN "Moins de 500 habitants"
        WHEN `ville_population_2012` >= 500 AND `ville_population_2012` <= 10000 THEN "Entre 500 et 10000 habitants"
        ELSE "Plus de 10000 habitants"
    END AS categorie,
    COUNT(*) AS nombre_villes
FROM `test`.villes_france_free
GROUP BY categorie;
```

The result with phpmyadmin :

[image]

How i can make the same result in birt ?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Of course you can use any query that your JDBC driver supports.

Comment: When i use this query birt no responding ....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN "ville_population_2012" < 500 THEN 'Moins de 500 habitants'
        WHEN "ville_population_2012" >= 500 AND "ville_population_2012" <= 10000 THEN 'Entre 500 et 10000 habitants'
        ELSE 'Plus de 10000 habitants'
    END AS categorie,
    COUNT(*) AS nombre_villes
FROM "test"."villes_france_free"
GROUP BY categorie;
```

Comment: When i use this query birt no responding ....